# How to pass assign variable value in FreeMarker function

Tags: freemarker

I want  to pass assign variable value to FreeMarker function but got following error:

> getSeourlDto(productid) is undefined.

```
<#function getSeourlDto id>
  <#list seourlsDto as seourl>
    <#if  id==seourl.objId>
      <#return (seourl)>
    </#if>
  </#list>


<#assign productid=product.id>

<#assign alias=getSeourlDto(productid)>
```

it got error  but working with hardcoded value

```
<#assign alias=getSeourlDto(198)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that the `seourlsDto` list doesn't contain the value of `productid`, hence the `#if` condition is never true and so the `#function` ends without `#return`. Hence the value of the `getSeourlDto(productid)` expression, which stands for the function return value, is undefined.

Comment: map value  <#assign productid="${product.id}">
                      ${seoUrlMap[productid]}

Comment: @kano: That just means `${seoUrlMap[product.id?string]}`. However if you need to do that, then you should do `${seoUrlMap[product.id?c]}`, because your keys are certainly not in an internationalized number format.